# Query to get the most recent quote for each ticker symbol distinctly

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In Meteor, I have a Quotes collection of price quotes which is a mix of all tracked symbols.  The Quotes collection looks like this:

```
{ "sym" : "CL", "bid" : 49.29, "ask" : 49.31, "timestamp" : 1424835506105, "_id" : "2yPrQzoZ8MTad8viw" }
{ "sym" : "CL", "bid" : 49.3, "ask" : 49.31, "timestamp" : 1424835512114, "_id" : "oMcsLm2qqkLqWDxpG" }
{ "sym" : "ZB", "bid" : 146.0625, "ask" : 146.09375, "timestamp" : 1424835529244, "_id" : "7XSDNAR8Hx6DmjWhg" }
{ "sym" : "NQ", "bid" : 4445.25, "ask" : 4445.75, "timestamp" : 1424835533854, "_id" : "3AgfZWYAbnWW7pGcc" }
{ "sym" : "YM", "bid" : 18181, "ask" : 18182, "timestamp" : 1424835540869, "_id" : "AQupJnnx2mNMLwSq5" }
{ "sym" : "ZB", "bid" : 146.0625, "ask" : 146.125, "timestamp" : 1424835540870, "_id" : "85eemh5pPQd469cMK" }
{ "sym" : "NQ", "bid" : 4445.25, "ask" : 4445.5, "timestamp" : 1424835540883, "_id" : "7cMmsJqoAkct2CPtm" }
{ "sym" : "NQ", "bid" : 4445.25, "ask" : 4445.75, "timestamp" : 1424835546572, "_id" : "r7zNAuqeQXL7jvnDv" }
{ "sym" : "YM", "bid" : 18181, "ask" : 18183, "timestamp" : 1424835546573, "_id" : "7Dxf2WmhibBuuZrg2" }
{ "sym" : "ES", "bid" : 2112.5, "ask" : 2113, "timestamp" : 1424835577420, "_id" : "yWKtqNjbtSoN2dMzc" }
{ "sym" : "YM", "bid" : 18181, "ask" : 18182, "timestamp" : 1424835577438, "_id" : "bWmmtvdAafxgaNRNJ" }
```

I would like to retrieve only the most recent quote for each sym, which means I need to combine distinct on sym with max on timestamp.  And I am doing this in Meteor.

Is there a single Quotes.find() command that will return this result set?

```
{ "sym" : "CL", "bid" : 49.3, "ask" : 49.31, "timestamp" : 1424835512114, "_id" : "oMcsLm2qqkLqWDxpG" }
{ "sym" : "ZB", "bid" : 146.0625, "ask" : 146.125, "timestamp" : 1424835540870, "_id" : "85eemh5pPQd469cMK" }
{ "sym" : "NQ", "bid" : 4445.25, "ask" : 4445.75, "timestamp" : 1424835546572, "_id" : "r7zNAuqeQXL7jvnDv" }
{ "sym" : "ES", "bid" : 2112.5, "ask" : 2113, "timestamp" : 1424835577420, "_id" : "yWKtqNjbtSoN2dMzc" }
{ "sym" : "YM", "bid" : 18181, "ask" : 18182, "timestamp" : 1424835577438, "_id" : "bWmmtvdAafxgaNRNJ" }
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Meteor 1.0.3.2 the [aggregate function is not supported](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)

But basing on an example from [the meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publishandsubscribe), you can observe changes to the collection on server in the publish function and return a dynamic collection with the aggregated values.

Here's how this would work in your case:

```js
// server: publish the current size of a collection
Meteor.publish("recentQuotes", function () {
  var self = this;

  // here we'll store information about which documents are used
  // as the most recent ones
  var onlyLastValues = {};

  var handle = Quotes.find({}, {sort: {timestamp: 1}}).observeChanges({

    // fired when a document is added to the Quotes collection
    added: function (id, fields) {

      if (onlyLastValues[fields.sym] === undefined)
        self.added("recentQuotesAll", fields.sym, fields);   
      else
        self.changed("recentQuotesAll", fields.sym, fields);  

      onlyLastValues[fields.sym] = id;

    },

    // fired when a document is removed from the Quotes collection
    // if that's one
    removed: function (id) {

      // as you only have id as a parameter you need to find  
      // which sym was changed

      onlyLastValuesById = _.invert(onlyLastValues);

      if (onlyLastValuesById[id] !== undefined){
        // the removed document was one of the last documents

        // search for last quote with that sym
        lastQuote = Quotes.findOne({sym: onlyLastValuesById[id]}, {sort: {timestamp: -1}});

        // remove if it was the last one
        if (lastQuote === undefined)
          self.removed("recentQuotesAll", onlyLastValuesById[id]); 

        else
          // modify the dynamic collection
          self.changed("recentQuotesAll", lastQuote.sym, lastQuote);    
      }

    },

    // fired when the document in Quotes collection is changed
    // need to check if that's one of the last quotes
    changed: function(id, fields){

      // this is fairly similar to removed

      onlyLastValuesById = _.invert(onlyLastValues);

      if (onlyLastValuesById[id] !== undefined){

        // this time we have all the fields already

        // modify the dynamic collection
        self.changed("recentQuotesAll", fields.sym, fields);    
      }
    }

  });

  self.ready();

  // Stop observing the cursor when client unsubs.
  // Stopping a subscription automatically takes
  // care of sending the client any removed messages.
  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
});

}

if (Meteor.isClient){

// client: declare collection to hold aggregated object
RecentQuotesAll = new Mongo.Collection("recentQuotesAll");

// client: subscribe to the aggregated values
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe("recentQuotes");
});
```

You could also add `initializing` variable to publish the data once it's fully counted for the first time. For that you'd have to store all fields in the `onlyLastValues` object and run `self.added` for each of the stored values right before the 
`self.ready();` 
call.

Comment: This looks very promising, but I'm not following some of your code.  You have introduced onlyLastValuesById in removed and changed, but there is no var in front of it.  I'm not sure if that's intentional or if it's even the problem.  I tried adding var, but either way I get this error:  "Exception in queued task: Error: Could not find element with id - to change"

Comment: Here's a meteorpad for you: http://meteorpad.com/pad/CME92i6eZ7SnHNPLi/Example%20for%20greymatter
I had some typos in the `added` function It's fixed now.

Comment: I didn't use var for `onlyLastValuesById` as I used this value only inside the scope of `changed`. It shouldn't really matter here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to query in `meteor` but below mongo aggregation will solve your problem

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$sort": {
    "timestamp": -1
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$sym",
    "bid": {
        "$first": "$bid"
    },
    "ask": {
        "$first": "$ask"
    },
    "timestamp": {
        "$first": "$timestamp"
    },
    "id": {
        "$first": "$_id"
    }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "sym": "$_id",
    "bid": "$bid",
    "ask": "$ask",
    "timestamp": "$timestamp",
    "_id": "$id"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
db.collection.aggregate({ "$group" : {"_id" : "$sym",
     "runtime" : {"$max" : "$timestamp"},
"bid":{$last:"$bid"},
"ask":{$last:"$ask"}
 }},

{ "$project" : {
     "sym" : "$_id" ,
     "runtime" : 1,
    "bid":1,
    "ask":1
 }
})
```